# Javascript date - Specify incoming date format (jQuery UI DateTimepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I'm using custom plugin for jQuery UI datepicker - [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

I have two fields, **from** and **to** input field, and need to check if **to "is greater than" from**. I have my custom onClose function (*onClose: function(dateText, inst) {}*), but the first parameter is value of input - a date string. But my date string is not in the "valid" JS datetime format so I'm not able to get Date object instance and compare.

It's **dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm**, e.g. 06.08.2012 12:00

I wonder if there is anything how to specify input string format, e.g.:

```
var date = new Date('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm', dateText);
```

If not I'll have you parse it somehow...

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such utility built in to JavaScript.  If I were you I would match the date format with a regex and use [the form of the Date constructor which accepts date parts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```javascript
function parseDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d)$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1], m[4], m[5]) : null;
}
```

Note that the month part is zero based (instead of one based, so January=0, hence the minux one).  Also, note that the [`Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is used to convert strings to numbers so you don't have to worry about numbers possibly prefixed with a zero being interpreted as octal as can happen with [`parseInt(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Variable m is always null for me...I have no idea why. I've tested it with Reqular Expression Tester for Firefox

Comment: Check the input string very carefully.  Does it have any additional whitespace (before? after? in between)?

Comment: I checked it there: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html - it was OK. And then I tried if(!new RegExp(/^(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d{4})\s(\d\d):(\d\d)$/).test(str)) on my localhost and got error, that str is invalid. There are no white spaces around, maybe the one in the middle...

Comment: I've tried this approach. but still null...........var regex = '/^(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d)$/';
            var re = new RegExp(regex);
            var m = re.exec($.trim(str));

Comment: I've just moved this function from my template file to .js file and included in <head> and it's working :) Thanks a lot for help.